# jQuery Sibilings DIV show/hide mouseout trigger

Tags: jquery, mouseevent, siblings

I am aware that they may be the same questions out there answered, i just can't seem to formulate my problem without showing my code:

I wish to have a DIV show on mouseover, however when i loose focus on the div the code naturally thinks i want it hidden again.. which i do but NOT when i change focus to the newly shown DIV. Any suggestions?

```
       $('.eventinfo2').mouseover(function(){
       $(this).parent().siblings('.snippetinfo').show();
   })
   $('.eventinfo2').mouseout(function(){
       $(this).parent().siblings('.snippetinfo').hide(); 

   });
```

the HTML:

```
<div class="container">
<div class="eventinfo2">
    ...
</div>
<div class="snippetinfo" style="display:none;">
...
</div>
```

Any help appreciated. I'm assuming i either need to set a variable and a conditional ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all, you can use `mouseenter` and `mouseleave`

You can easily target the group by wrapping them in a `div`

Secondly, in your code, eventinfo2 and snippetinfo are siblings.  If necessary target `siblings()` not `parent().sliblings()` because the latter will refer to elements that are withing the same container as 'container'

Here you go [EXAMPLE](http://jsfiddle.net/uqvQ3/1/)

```
   $('#foo').on('mouseenter', function(){
       $('.snippetinfo').show();
   })

    $('#foo').on('mouseleave', function(){
        $('.snippetinfo').hide(); 

   });
```